# Implementation of the Fourier transform of the option price as a function of the characteristic function Carr Madan method

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance, quantitative-finance

Psi in the Carr Madan method of option pricing is the Fourier transform of the option price as a function of the characteristic function.

The function psi should return a scalar as opposed to a vector which is causing me the problem. So I am looking for suggestions of alternative implementation.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma

param = [24.79, 94.45, 95.79, 0.2495, 0]
alpha = 1.1
lnS = 4.142976
r = 0.05
Sigma = 0.25
scale = 1

FFT_N = int(np.power(2,15))
uvec = np.linspace(1,FFT_N,FFT_N)
vj = (uvec-1) * 0.5
Tmt = 1/12

def psi(CF, vj, alpha, lnS, T=Tmt):
    u=vj-(alpha*1j+1j)
    denom = alpha**2 + alpha - Sigma**2 + vj * 2 * alpha * 1j + 1j * vj
    return CF(u,lnS, Tmt)/denom

CF=lambda u, lnS, T: cf_log_cgmy(u=u, lnS=lnS, T=Tmt, mu=r, half_etasq=param[4],C=param[0], G=param[1], M=param[2], Y=param[3])

def cf_log_cgmy(u, lnS, T, mu ,half_etasq, C, G, M, Y):

    omega = -C*gamma(-Y)*(np.power(M-1,Y)-np.power(M,Y)+np.power(G+1,Y)-np.power(G,Y ))
    phi_CGMY = C*T*gamma(-Y)*(np.power(M-1j*u,Y)-np.power(M,Y)+np.power(G+1j*u,Y)- np.power(G,Y))
    phi = 1j*u*(lnS + (mu+omega-half_etasq)*T) + phi_CGMY - half_etasq*np.power(u,2)
    return np.exp(scale*phi)


psi(CF, vj, alpha, lnS, T=Tmt)
```

The psi function stands for equation (6) on page 64 of the attached below paper

https://engineering.nyu.edu/sites/default/files/2018-08/CarrMadan2_0.pdf

Comment: You might already know that **the paper-PDF does not show Eqn#-s** after (2) and has several other variable-referencing errors / LaTeX flaws in typesetting, so better post a more readable version.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what does your comment mean. Do you mind to rephrase it. Do you have an example?

Comment: In the referenced PDF, there are 4 equations on the page 64, yet none has a number at the right edge, as opposed to page 62, where at least one of the three equations there was labeled with an equation number ( printed "(1)" at the right edge ) or the page 63, where only one gets the label ( "(2)", though misplaced on the left edge, slightly under the such labeled equation ) and none other on all the rest of the pages of the PDF-document. Other errors show Psi-sub( *T*-maturity )-function-of-(v) mis-typed on many places on page 64, so Marguerite did indeed a bad LaTeX job that nobody corrected